# ¿Alguno me podría explicar cómo funciona aquella función?

Tags: javascript, funciones

```
const factorial = function fac(n) { return n < 2 ? 1 : n * fac(n - 1) }
console.log(factorial(3))
```

No entiendo lo de los signos '<', '?'

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu [primera medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: El primero es el símbolo de menor que, lo demás incluyendo el ? Es el operador ternario así busca en internet

Comment: Si n es menor de 2, se cumple la condición y se ejecuta la parte desde ? hasta :, si no, se cumple la parte desde : hasta el final, por tanto, si n < 2 devolverá 1 y si no, devolverá n * fac(n-1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lo que se ve aquí es un operador ternario.

```
const factorial = function fac(n) { return n < 2 ? 1 : n * fac(n - 1) }
console.log(factorial(3))
```

La función fac(n) es una función recursiva, esto quiere decir que se repetirá mientras se cumpla determinada condición de pare, por esta razón se vuelve a introducir dentro de la misma.

lo que hace es retornar 1 mientras n sea menor que 2 (esta es su condición de parada)

```
n<2 ? 1
```

luego de esto, en caso no se cumpla va a multiplicar a n * el valor que retorne la misma función con parámetro n-1.

Esto lo evalúa con un operador ternario, la cual su sintaxis es:

```
condición ? expresión1 : expresión2;
```

La forma en que se usa es la siguiente:

```
variable = expresion ? valor_verdad: valor_si_es_falso;
```

Te invito a leer un poco sobre operador ternario.
[Ternarios](https://devcode.la/tutoriales/operador-ternario-javascript/)

Y también sobre recursividad
[recursividad](https://www.campusmvp.es/recursos/post/Que-es-la-recursividad-o-recursion-Un-ejemplo-con-JavaScript.aspx)

Comment: Gracias, soy nuevo en esto y me sirvió mucho la ayuda

Answer (score 3):

`?` y `:` son [operadores condicionales ternarios](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Conditional_Operator). Son otra manera de escribir **`ìf`** (?) y **`else`** (:). Lo que tienes antes del signo `?` es la condición.

Por lo qué el siguiente código:

```
const factorial = function fac(n) { 
    return n < 2 ? 1 : n * fac(n - 1) 
}
```

Es equivalente a lo siguiente:

```
const factorial = function fac(n) { 
    if (n < 2) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return n * fac(n - 1);
    }
}
```

Te recomiendo leer el enlace que te he proporcionado.

Comment: Wou, mil gracias, ya lo capté

Comment: @JoseFlores recuerda si te sirvió la puedes marcar como aceptada